# How to use IF THEN ELSE statement in where clause in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm interesting that how can I use if-then-else statement or any control structure in where clause in Oracle. I want to use as:

- when `pcustomer_id IS NULL` then `WHERE c.customer_id IS NULL`
- and when `pcustomer_id IS NOT NULL` then `c.customer_id = pcustomer_id`.

How can I do it?

```
SELECT *
  FROM customer_inf c
 WHERE 
IF
 pcustomer_id IS NULL THEN ( c.customer_id IS NULL ) 
    ELSE (c.customer_id = pcustomer_id) END IF;
```

Comment: you can use case when in where clause

Comment: Have you tried searching? there are many similar questions in SO

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to bundle them

```
where (
(pcustomer_id is null 
    and c.customer_id is null)
or 
(pcustomer_id is not null 
    and c.customer_id = pcustomer_id)
)
```

Comment: Why do you need to check for `pcustomer_id is not null` in the second branch? The equality wouldn't hold if it was null anyway.

Comment: @mathguy That's true, but including it makes the solution easier to follow.

Answer (score 1):

Use boolean expressions:

```
SELECT *
FROM   customer_inf c
WHERE  ( pcustomer_id IS NULL AND c.customer_id IS NULL )
OR     ( pcustomer_id IS NOT NULL AND cc.customer_id = pcustomer_id);
```

Comment: Why do you need to check for `pcustomer_id is not null` in the second branch? The equality wouldn't hold if it was null anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you just want to return all values when c.customer_id = pcustomer_id including null equity. So:

```
select * from customer_inf c 
where nvl(pcustomer_id,'999999999999') = nvl(c.customer_id, '999999999999');
```

You just need to select number that cannot occur in your real data.

Comment: This solution depends on an assumption, that you will know beforehand of a string that will never be an id. In most organizations an assumption like this will make the solution fail code review.

Comment: You're almost always able to put identifier that is much longer or much shorter that all really used ids. And this is only sollution to avoid or/unions which affect performance. Especially OR.

Comment: Wrapping id's within functions has exactly the same effect on performance as does "or"; in fact, the optimizer may be able to work around "or" but not around nvl calls.

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE NVL(pcustomer_id,c.customer_id) IS NULL OR NVL2(pcustomer_id,c.customer_id,pcustomer_id)=pcustomer_id
```

Explanation:
Here, in first NVL if pcustomer_id is null then c.customer_id is passed and will check for Null
in second NVL2 1if pcustomer_id not null then c.customer_id = pcustomer_id